# Syntax error while printing in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

Following code works fine when running from a file.

```
count = 0
while count < 10:
     count = count + 1
     if count == 5:
         break
     print("inside loop", count)
print("out of while loop")
```

Output:

[image]

But when i tried to run the same code from python 2 console i get `SyntaxError`

[image]

Comment: Do not use " in print. Write like  `print "out of while loop"`.

Comment: @StanleyR still not working